# R Project - summary output of glht function in tab delimited form?

Tags: r, excel

I've used the function `lme()` in a database I've got. After that, I've used `glht()` in order to see the multiple comparisons of means. The summary of `glht()` gives me, in the linear hypotheses, 4 columns, with the last one (Pr(>|z|)) being the one I'm interest at, at the moment.

Because I'm dealing with 20 parameters, 4 different treatments, in 10 different groups, it is our plan to create a "heat map" of the *p* values obtained in the last column of `summary(glht())`.

My original plan is to copy and paste these values into Excel, and there I can make this heat map. However, `summary()` in R divides the columns with empty spaces, which is not helpful to send to Excel.

I've got 2 questions, then: (1) is it possible to change `summary()` in such a way all the values are tab delimited? (2) does anyone have a better/faster way of preparing this heat map? For this last question, I've thought about populating a matrix with the *p* values in R, as a starter. However, I'm not sure how to call this Pr(>|z|) column from the `summary()` function.

Many thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: `summary(glht()))$test$pvalues` should give you the p-values on the individual coefficients against a null of =0.  You can then format them as you wish.

Comment: Cool, thanks Gavin! I can now send them to Excel through `writeClipboard()` function, or if I have a bit more of time, I'll populate a matrix with that. Many thanks for the help!